# Bindable Picker in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

Is the Picker Control available in Xamarin bindable? If so, could someone help on how to use it ? I would like to bind a Picker control with data (XAML approach) that comes from a DB.

Comment: Here is the complete solution:

https://hiranpeiris.com/2017/02/24/how-to-add-a-custom-bindable-property-to-xamarin-forms-control/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bindable Picker is available since 13th January 2017. Currently, it is contained in version 2.3.4.184-pre1.
If you want to use it, you have to install Xamarin.Forms via nuget using the `-Pre` flag. Or check the Prerelease checkbox in the nuget UI.

> Install-Package Xamarin.Forms -Pre

And then, you can just bind your collection to `ItemsSource`.

```
<Picker
    Title="Select a Color"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" />
```

Announcement: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-xamarin-forms-pre-release-2-3-4-pre1-quality-improvements-bindable-picker

It will be released as stable not later than February 2017 (according to the [Roadmap](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can us the Picker control in Xamarin Forms.
Please check this link for the description: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Example #1 :
Use Extendedpicker of `xlabs` following is link to implement extended picker

Cs code of extended picker
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedPicker.cs

Implementation in xaml page:-
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/7a58dc349f17351813afa24df97ef7fea545a833/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples/Pages/Controls/ExtendedPickerPage.xaml

Example #2:
Try to create own bendable picker refer following link
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution:

https://hiranpeiris.com/2017/02/24/how-to-add-a-custom-bindable-property-to-xamarin-forms-control/

Create your custom picker class.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FDNet
{
    public class OutletPicker : Picker
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemSource), typeof(List<string>), typeof(OutletPicker), null);

        public List<string> ItemSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (List<string>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (propertyName == nameof(ItemSource))
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                if (ItemSource != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in ItemSource)
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Add XAML reference variable to the Page.

   ```
   xmlns:local=“clr–namespace:FDNet;assembly=FDNet“
   ```
3. Add the control and bind the property.

   ```
   <local:OutletPicker Title=“Select“ ItemSource=“{Binding Outlets}“ HorizontalOptions=“Center“ WidthRequest=“300“ />
   ```

Now you can see our custom bindable property   ItemSource=“{Binding Outlets}“)

4. Demo.

   ```
   Outlets = new List<string> { “4G LTE“, “4G Broadband“, “Fiber connection“ };

   <local:OutletPicker Title=“Select“ ItemSource=“{Binding Outlets}“ HorizontalOptions=“Center“ WidthRequest=“300“ />
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(1)bind picker :

Dictionary dicobj= new Dictionary();

```
 dicobj.Add(1, "abc");

dicobj.Add(2, "xyz");





 foreach (var item in dicobj.Values)

  {


 YorPickerName.Items.Add(item);

   }
```

(2)then get the selected value on SelectedIndexChanged event of picker:

```
  var selval = Service_category.SelectedIndex;

  int value = dicobj.ElementAt(selval).Key;

  var data = Service_category.Items[selval];

  int id = dicval.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == data).Key;
```